# Android share to Readability

Tags: android, share, readability

I have Readability app installed and want to share via it using simple Share Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name); 
intent.setType("text/plain"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 

if(info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.readability")) { 
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link); 
}
....
```

But it keeps telling me this:

[image]

So what should I pass or do to share via Readability?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it's expecting a URL in the intent's data field or in an extra field it has defined itself.